# Equivalent of modulus (math function) in C?

Tags: c, operators, modulus

I have a piece of code where I see a warning saying

**I am doing a comparison between signed and unsigned number .

Something like int <= CONSTANT/sizeof(expression)**

What is the best way to correct this? I believe to take the modulus of signed number and then do the comparison, right? I mean I get the unsigned number after division by sizeof operator on an expression. So the other way could be to make this rhs signed

If so is there a function in c that would let me do this? I did a quick search and they say % for modulo which obviously is not what I am looking for.

This is the actual warning

> warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions

and this is the actual line of code

> functionA( ......, int num, .....) {
>
> assert( num <= MAX_SIZE/sizeof(int));//where MAX_SIZE is #define
>   MAX_SIZE 1000
>
> }

Comment: If you mention warnings and errors in your questions, you might want to write down the actual warning and not your approximate version of it. And if you could let it be accompanied by some relevant code, that would be even better.

Comment: Added original code and warning above.

Comment: the question is, what is the intended allowed range that `num` may take? The size-related expressions make me indeed wonder what the goal of using modulo-operator or `abs`-function may be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just cast one side to the other signedness. You have to make sure that the signed number is not negative if you cast that to unsigned - otherwise a comparison of `-1 < 100` will not have the desired outcome, since `(unsigned)(-1) == UINT_MAX` -, or that the unsigned number doesn't overflow if you cast that to signed. In those cases, add an additional condition to treat them.

For the above particular case, I would use

```
assert(num <= (int)(MAX_SIZE/sizeof(int)));
// num <= MAX_SIZE/(int)sizeof(int) if I'm in a mean mood
```

if `num` might be negative and

```
assert((unsigned)num <= MAX_SIZE/sizeof(int));
```

if `num` is guaranteed to be nonnegative.

Comment: Thanks! So which brings me to my first question is there a modulus( one that we use in mathematics) operator in C? Something which does |-5|=5?

Comment: Do you mean `abs()` instead of modulus?

Comment: Casting a signed number to an unsigned type is safe, but not the other way around.

Comment: @Bart- Yeah exactly ! something like that but isnt abs() a C++ function?

Comment: @Manish: It's a C function too :)

Comment: @dreamlax casting from signed to unsigned is defined behaviour, but will not yield the intended behaviour in most cases of `-1 <= 17` where `-1` is signed and `17` unsigned.

Comment: @dreamlax - In C it's supposed to return and int ..so it doesnt correct my problem :( http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/abs/

Answer (score 2):

If you know the right operand is <= `INT_MAX`, you can cast it to `int`.

```
int bla;

...

if (bla < (int) sizeof expr) {
    ...
}
```

But if you can change the type of object `bla` to `size_t` (which is the type of the value that `sizeof` yields) it would be even better than to cast.

Comment: OP said `bla` is signed, so you can't just change it to `size_t` (which is unsigned).

Answer (score 1):

As I see this, your `int num` is allowed to take any negative value and positive values up to `MAX_SIZE/sizeof(int)`. Otherwise you would have declared `num` as an unsigned integer for sure...

Would extending your assertion statement by this additional condition help in your case?

```
assert( num < 0 || /* make the signed check */
  (unsigned int)num <= MAX_SIZE/sizeof(int) /* the unsigned remainder */
  );
```